# How do I fix the error \ BuildConfig.java (The system can not find the specified path)?

Tags: android-studio

**I'm trying to compile a buildbox game.**

buildconfig.java says:

> BuildConfig.java (The system can not find the specified path)

What it's up to is to create the `buildconfig.java` in the specified path but when entering the buildconfig.java it tells me this:

> files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited.

When doing a sync it will delete the `BuildConfig.java` and this prevents me from compiling the project. Please help.

Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: maybe you can fix it from your android studio this is the project with the problem: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19IW0mSuFqHxhxxq-Mu-89J8UgPyfKYaa and this is the buildconfig.java: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YZY4KsvQHju26Lj9mb46IyRbWBWx4dsP

and if you can not fix it, try to do another procedure. This is the unencrypted project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-kC6A9lxN-j2xnO15CeDns1F0jwcUcj4

if you are lucky in solving it do not forget to tell me I could give you the game program in 2d without code

Answer (score -1):

maybe the space on the reddimbounce package name on androidmanifest or on other files , thats the reason why theres a space on error "reddimbounce \buildconfig.java"